# How to retrieve model associated to view when click event happens

Tags: view, model, ember.js

I've got the following template

```
{{#each photo in photos}}
    {{#view App.PhotoView}}
        <img {{bindAttr src="photo.cover_image_source" data-photo-id="photo.id"}} />
    {{/view}}
{{/each}}
```

Now in my PhotoView, how do I access the photo model associated to it when the click event is triggered?

```
App.PhotoView = Ember.View.extend({
    click: function(event) {
        // how do I retrieve the model ????
    }
})
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

This can actually be achieved with much less code using `itemViewClass`.

```
{{#each photos itemViewClass="App.PhotoView"}}
  <img {{bindAttr src="cover_image_source"}} />
{{/each}}
```

Each view automatically sets the context to the item in the photos array.

```
App.PhotoView = Ember.View.extend({
  click: function(event) {
    var photo = this.get("context");
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The model is not automatically passed into the click function handler, so it's not direct accessible in the view, but you can get the model differently, eighter by using the itemViewClass as @BradleyPriest mentioned or hook into the view's controller to catch the event. - here a jsfiddle that shows that concept - http://jsfiddle.net/intuitivepixel/AywvW/27/

**EDIT: I've edited my answer to match the jsfiddle**

Template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
{{#each photo in photos}}
  {{#view App.PhotoView contentBinding="photo"}}
    <a {{action "photoClicked" photo}}>
      <img {{bindAttr src="photo.cover_image_source"}} />
    </a>
  {{/view}}
{{/each}}
</script>
```

View

```
App.PhotoView = Ember.View.extend({
  content: null
});
```

Controller

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  photoClicked: function(event) {
    alert(event.title);
  }
});
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. That's why I had put the data-photo-id attr. I wish it were a little like Backbone and Backbone Marionette. Makes it a lot easier.

Comment: normally you would do this in a total different manner, wrapping the image in an {{action}} helper so you could pass the model along to the function you want to call...

Comment: Oh I'll check the action stuff. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I tried the code and am getting 'Uncaught Error: Nothing handled the event 'photoClicked'. '

Comment: I had to move the photoClicked function to a router, which is not even the router matching the template. It's hard to understand why. Also this.getPath is deprecated in 1.0.0-rc3

Comment: I'm sorry that my code didn't work out... I've put a fiddle togheter that works: http://jsfiddle.net/intuitivepixel/AywvW/27

Comment: Thanks a lot. Maybe it's because my situation is different. I'm using nested routes.